# How to get Single object in sequelize association using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Below code I associate two table [user and addresses].Associate properly and i get output also but not single object

```
return myDb.user.findAll({
                                attributes: ['ID','NAME'],

                                include: [{
                                  model: myDb.addresses,
                                  as: 'addresses',
                                  attributes:['ADDRESS_1','ADDRESS_2','CITY','STATE','POSTCODE'],

                                }]
                              })
                              .then((getCustomer) => {

                              .........
                              ........
```

above code Output:

```
    {


        "ID" : "fgfhgdsfg4323",
        "NAME" : "MR.X",
        "addresses": [
            {
                "ADDRESS_1": "BBB",
                "ADDRESS_2": "GGG",
                "CITY": "TTT",
                "STATE": "NNN",
                "POSTCODE": ""
            }
        ]
    }
```

My expected Output:

```
{
    "ID" : "fgfhgdsfg4323",
    "NAME" : "MR.X",
    "ADDRESS_1": "BBB",
    "ADDRESS_2": "GGG",
    "CITY": "TTT",
    "STATE": "NNN",
    "POSTCODE": ""
}
```

How to get My expected Output ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if there are multiple addresses?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it like this:

```
 return myDb.user.findAll({
     attributes:['ID','NAME','addresses.ADDRESS_1','addresses.ADDRESS_2','addresses.CITY','addresses.STATE','addresses.POSTCODE'],
     include: [{
     model: myDb.addresses,
     as: 'addresses',
     attributes:[],    }],    raw:true, 
 });
```

You will have to fetch associated data with the base model data & raw will be defined as true.

Comment: but there is a problem that my result has result like this address.state address.city I want them as state, city

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq You can simply define aliases in attributes array like this -

attributes:['ID','NAME',['addresses.ADDRESS_1','ADDRESS_1'],['addresses.ADDRESS_2',,'ADDRESS_2']],

This will give the column name as same as you want.

Comment: this is not working

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq What error you getting when using above snippet ?

Comment: but there is a problem that my result has result like this address.state address.city I want them as state, city.

Answer (score 0):

I presume here you have a one-to-many relationship. So multiple `addresses` to a single user. Ofcorse it will return an array of `addresses`

If you want a single object like that, and are assuming there is a single address for that user, simply process the data after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing relationships, it will show you as array, but if you need desired output you can try this:

```js
var data =     
    {
        "ID" : "fgfhgdsfg4323",
        "NAME" : "MR.X",
        "addresses": [
            {
                "ADDRESS_1": "BBB",
                "ADDRESS_2": "GGG",
                "CITY": "TTT",
                "STATE": "NNN",
                "POSTCODE": ""
            }
        ]
    }
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.addresses.length; i++){
  result.push({
    "ID" : data.ID,
    "NAME" : data.NAME,
    "ADDRESS_1": data.addresses[i].ADDRESS_1,
    "ADDRESS_2": data.addresses[i].ADDRESS_2,
    "CITY": data.addresses[i].CITY,
    "STATE": data.addresses[i].STATE,
    "POSTCODE": data.addresses[i].POSTCODE  
  })
  
 console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: If this works according to your question, accept this answer :)

Comment: wat iteration? explain!

Comment: iteration means -- for loop

Comment: How you will get array data if there are more than 100 arrays without doing forEach or for ?